# Exclude zip artifact dependency

Tags: teamcity

I have an Artifact Dependency for a build which produces two zip files. I only require one of the zip files but it keeps downloading both files, or gives an error, no matter what I try to specify to exclude the second.

The format of the file names is similar to `App_1.1.1103.zip` and `App_1.1.1103_trial.zip`, where `1.1.1103` is the version and build number.

The artifact paths I have defined are:

```
+:App*.zip!/**/*=>%AppFolder%
-:App*trial.zip
```

Both files are always downloaded and extracted to the same location with the second one overwriting files from the first.

How do I exclude the second zip when using the unzip syntax?